# Native Function Return from Geography Data Type

Tags: jboss, ddl, teiid

I am creating a DDL file to be deployed as VDB using TEIID.
The source model is MS SQl. In the source database there is geography data type column. I am trying to read the lat and long from geography data type.

To retrieve the lat/long in sql server:

```
db.geogCol.Lat
db.geogCol.Long
```

When creating a view in ddl file using select statement and trying to retrieve the lat/long by passing to teiid, an exception is thrown. Teiid seems to think .Lat and .Long are columns whereas they are sql server function tied to the geography data column. How can i execute this so it treats the above arguments as ms-sql

Answer (score 1):

The closest representation is a source function.  You will need to create source functions to represent them.  On the sql server schema:

```
create foreign function lat (geography geog) returns double
  OPTIONS ("teiid_rel:native-query" '$1.Lat');
```

and a similar one for Long.

Teiid does have the st_x and st_y functions, but I don't think they are eligible for pushdown to sql server currently.

Comment: That worked. Thanks ! Except I had to pass the value as `(val varbinary)`